# C# calling a Java web service method that has a List input parameter

Tags: c#, java, web-services

I have a web service written in Java (hosted on JBoss) with a method that has a List input parameter.

```
public void saveMultipleDirective(List<OwordDirective> directives)
```

The issue I'm having is that my C# client (which is a Windows desktop application), cannot see that method. That method is there in the WSDL, but I cannot access it from my C# client.

[image: Missing method.]

If I go ahead and do the following...

```
SaveMultipleDirective save = new SaveMultipleDirective();
```

I get the following error: The type or namespace name 'SaveMultipleDirective' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If I change the input parameter to a String, I then could see that method in my C# client.

Is there a way for me to call this type of method from C#?

Thanks!

Comment: You will save yourself a lot of time if you change `List<OwordDirective>` to `OwordDirective[]` on the java webservice side. You can easily convert the array to a list once inside the java ws method.

Comment: I tried that as well, but the result was the same, C# could not see the method.